# What is the easiest way to convert JSON into BSON in .net world

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson

I just started working on MongoDB. From my JavaScript client I am sending a JSON string to ASP.NET WEB API project. Is it possible to use this JSON string directly and save it into MongoDB? I also want to know whether this approach make sense ?

I am thinking of passing the `JSON` from client and on the server side read the `string` as

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public dynamic SaveData([FromBody] string data)
    {

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[0]
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string json = "...";
BsonDocument.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
string json = "{ 'foo' : 'bar' }";
MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document
= MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
but keep in mind that sending client side data without check the user data can lead to security issues (Never Trust The User's Input)
You can do this by using the [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) Collection Methods.
keep in mind that if you will not have _id in your json Mongodb will produced it for you.

for example i will create a document in the "test" Collection like that

```
db.test.insert(
 {
   "foo":"bar"
 }
);
```

and the result can be something like that

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c9be08e66b0571a5e3965"),
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```